# How to do currying with UnderscoreJS?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am a bit experimenting with `_.bind(...)`. I see how to force a function context with bind, but don't yet see how to do currying.

What I try is this:

```
 add = function(number) { this.sum = this.sum + number; }
 add5 = _.bind(add, { sum: 0 }, 5)
```

However, calling `add5()`, or `add5(5)` seems not to have some effects.

Any clues how to do wrap the arguments such that the context is preserved from one call to another?

Comment: Underscore has a `_.partial`, which I think you can use to curry.

Comment: Neither `add` nor `add5` *have* effects, so what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I was expecting to get some numbers: 0, 5, 10, 15, ...

Comment: Where would they be printed? You have no code to show numbers.

Comment: see also https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/pull/474

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you want to do *partial application*, not currying/schönfinkeling. Underscore has the [`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) function for this:

```
function add(a, b) { return a+b; }
var add5 = _.partial(add, 5);
```

You can as well use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), and it *has* some effects. For example:

```
var add5 = _.bind(add, null /*context is irrelevant*/, 5);
add5(3); // returns 8
```

Yet, your function did not return anything, and the context which you did change was not accessible. However:

```
var ctx1 = {sum: 0};
function add(a) { this.sum += a; } // returns nothing!
var addto1 = _.bind(add, ctx1);
addto1(5); // undefined
ctx1; // {sum: 5}

var add5to1 = _.bind(add, ctx1, 5);
add5to1(); // undefined
ctx1; // {sum: 10}

var ctx2 = {sum: 5};
add3to2 = _.bind(add, ctx2, 3);
add3to2(); // undefined
ctx2; // {sum: 8}
```

Comment: Thanks, hmm... actually, I am trying to understand that binding context onto a function. Any idea, why some discussions mention the 'binding' as 'currying' ? Any example with number objects that would apply to _.bind() ?

Comment: Yeah, many get that wrong. This Wikipedia entry explains it quite well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application

Comment: Ok, so, basically, the bind() like above is partial application, or? Or, is there any subtle detail that would make it currying?

Comment: another reference to this discussion might be: http://ngauthier.com/2012/04/var-self-equals-lame.html

Comment: Yes, `bind` (and its [native equivalent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) does partial application, but it especially "sets" that JS-specific `thisArg` context argument.